# simplex volume in terms of facet areas

Tags: geometry, simplex

It is known since ancient times how the volume of triangle can be expressed in terms of its edge lengths ([Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)). Is there a generalization for simplices that specifies the volume of an $n$-dimensional simplex in terms of the areas of its facets?

(I'm not looking for the [Cayley-Menger determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Menger_determinant) which gives the $n$-volume in terms of all edge lengths.)

Comment: The big issue is to define what you call the "area" of $n$-dimensional facets... Besides, have a look at De Gua's theorem 
 and its generalization (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Gua%27s_theorem)

Comment: See the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1587319)

Comment: Even in three dimensions, there's a problem: a tetrahedron admits *six* degrees of freedom, but faces account for only *four*. My personal "hedronometric" research introduces the notion of three pseudo-faces to make up the deficit. (There's a relation between face and pseudo-face areas that reduces the degrees of freedom to six.) With these, volume can be uniquely determined. See [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3262305/409) to ["Does knowing the surface area of all faces uniquely determine a tetrahedron?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3262238/409)

Comment: @JeanMarie What's meant by "surface area" is clear: The sum of the areas of all facets. The question you link is mostly concerned with the fact that a common formula only works if the spatial dimension matches that of the simplex.

Comment: @Blue The question you're linking is a little too specific: A simplex might not be uniquely determined by its surface areas alright. But its volume might be. (Perhaps not, but I fail to see it.)

Comment: @NicoSchlömer: Read the "extreme example" in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3262305/409). (See also the introduction to my ["Heron-like Results for Tetrahedral Volume" (PDF link via daylateanddollarshort.com](http://daylateanddollarshort.com/mathdocs/Heron-like-Results-for-Tetrahedral-Volume.pdf) Tetrahedra with four equal face areas range in volume from $0$ to a maximum for regular tetrahedra. Four areas simply aren't enough to determine a tetrahedron's volume.

Comment: Thanks @Blue for the clarification. If you provide an answer with just that link, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promoting comments to an answer, as requested:

---

Even in three dimensions, there's a problem: a tetrahedron admits six degrees of freedom, but faces account for only four. My personal "hedronometric" research introduces the notion of three pseudo-faces to make up the deficit. (There's a relation between face and pseudo-face areas that reduces the degrees of freedom to six.) With these, volume can be uniquely determined.

See [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3262305/409) to the question ["Does knowing the surface area of all faces uniquely determine a tetrahedron?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3262238/409).

I'll echo here that my note ["Heron-like Results for Tetrahedral Volume" (PDF link via daylateanddollarshort.com)](http://daylateanddollarshort.com/mathdocs/Heron-like-Results-for-Tetrahedral-Volume.pdf) considers this topic at length. You don't have to take my own word for it, though; as mentioned in the note (as Theorem 7), Gerber proved in 1975 that a tetrahedron whose opposite edges are orthogonal maximizes volume for a given set of face-areas. We wouldn't need that result if face-areas determined volume uniquely.